# Group pandas dataframe by quantile of single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if this is duplicate post - I can't find a related post though

```
from random import seed
seed(100)
P = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

What I'd like is to group `P` by the quartiles/quantiles/deciles/etc of column `A` and then calculate a aggregate statistic (such as `mean`) by group. I can define deciles of the column as

```
P['A'].quantile(np.arange(10) / 10)
```

I'm not sure how to groupby the deciles of `A`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to group `P` e.g. by quartiles, run:

```
gr = P.groupby(pd.qcut(P.A, 4, labels=False))
```

Then you can perform any operations on these groups.

For presentation, below you have just a printout of `P` limited to
20 rows:

```
for key, grp in gr:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

which gives:

```
Group: 0
     A   B
0    8  24
3   10  94
10   9  93
15   4  91
17   7  49

Group: 1
     A   B
7   34  24
8   15  60
12  27   4
13  31   1
14  13  83

Group: 2
     A   B
4   52  98
5   53  66
9   58  16
16  59  67
18  47  65

Group: 3
     A   B
1   67  87
2   79  48
6   98  14
11  86   2
19  61  14
```

As you can see, each group (quartile) has 5 members, so the grouping is
correct.

## As a supplement

If you are interested in **borders** of each quartile, run:

```
pd.qcut(P.A, 4, labels=False, retbins=True)[1]
```

Then `cut` returns 2 results (a tuple). The first element (number 0) is
the result returned before, but we are this time interested in the
**second** element (number 1) - the bin borders.

For your data they are:

```
array([ 4.  , 12.25, 40.5 , 59.5 , 98.  ])
```

So e.g. the first quartile is between *4* and *12.35*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `quantile` Series to make another column, to marking each row with its quantile label, and then group by that column. [numpy searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is very useful to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import seed

seed(100)
P = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
q = P['A'].quantile(np.arange(10) / 10)
P['G'] = P['A'].apply(lambda x : q.index[np.searchsorted(q, x, side='right')-1])
```

Since the quantile Series stores the lower values of the quantile intervals, be sure to pass the parameter `side='right'` to `np.searchsorted` to not get 0 (the minimum should be 1 or you have one index more than you need).

Now you can elaborate your statistics by doing, for example:

```
P.groupby('G').agg(['sum', 'mean']) #add to the list all the statistics method you wish
```

Comment: Sorry - had to give the checkmark to `pd.qcut` - assuming it is more performant

Comment: No worries. I didn't know about `qcut`, I learned something too thanks to @Valdi_Bo 's answer. I don't know about performances, but `qcut` seems done specifically for this task, so it's likely to be more efficient than my solution.