# split a dataframe into quartiles of a specific column

Tags: dataframe

I would like to split a dataframe into 4 dataframes named q1, q2, q3 and q4 where q1 should contain all rows where a specific column (e.g. age) is among the lowest 25% of the (age) distribution, q2 from 25% to 50%, q3 from 50% to 75% and q4 from 75% to 100%. Or in other words: I would like to create 4 equally sized groups of persons based on their age.

How can I do this in a pythonic way (currently I am using loops but that's possibly not a great solution)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58041129/7283201).

Comment: You can also use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty but does the trick (if anybody is interested):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 100], [2, 10], [3, 1], [4, 50], [5, 43], [6, 61], [7, 99], [7, 11]]), columns=['idx', 'age'])

print(df)

q = df.quantile([0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00])

col = 'age'

q1 = df[((df[col]>=q[col][0.00]) & (df[col]<q[col][0.25]))]
q2 = df[((df[col]>=q[col][0.25]) & (df[col]<q[col][0.50]))]
q3 = df[((df[col]>=q[col][0.50]) & (df[col]<q[col][0.75]))]
q4 = df[((df[col]>=q[col][0.75]) & (df[col]<=q[col][1.00]))]
print('----')
print(q1)
print('----')
print(q2)
print('----')
print(q3)
print('----')
print(q4)
```

yields:

```
   idx  age
0    1  100
1    2   10
2    3    1
3    4   50
4    5   43
5    6   61
6    7   99
7    7   11
----
   idx  age
1    2   10
2    3    1
----
   idx  age
4    5   43
7    7   11
----
   idx  age
3    4   50
5    6   61
----
   idx  age
0    1  100
6    7   99
```

Comment: is there something more pretty/efficient?